# Réplica no datagridview (vb.net e ms-access database)

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-access

Quando estou efectuando uma nova venda (no caso de este software que estou desenvolvendo), toda vez que adiciono novos items no datagridview ele apareçe juntamente com items(ou vendas) adicionados anteriormente. Gostaria de limpar o datagridview antes de adicionar novos items(ou efectuar nova venda).

Estou usando o codigo abaixo, porém não está resultando.

```
Private Sub lvTable_ItemChecked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles lvTable.ItemChecked
    Try

        If lvTable.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Dim Condition As String = ""
            Dim Condition1 As String = ""
            For I = 0 To lvTable.CheckedItems.Count - 1

                Condition += String.Format("'{0}',", lvTable.CheckedItems(I).Text)
                Condition1 += String.Format("'{0}',", lvTable.CheckedItems(I).SubItems(1).Text)
            Next
            Condition = Condition.Substring(0, Condition.Length - 1)
            Condition1 = Condition1.Substring(0, Condition1.Length - 1)
            DataGridView2.Visible = True
            con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
            con.Open()
            Dim OleDb As String = "Select Item_ID,DishName, SUM(Qty), KOTGenerationItems.Rate, SUM(Amount), DiscPer, SUM(Disc), VATPer, SUM(VATAmt), STPer, SUM(STAmt), SCPer, SUM(SCAmt), SUM(TotalAmt),TableNo,GroupName from KOTGeneration,KOTGenerationItems,Dish where KOTGeneration.TicketID=KOTGenerationItems.Ticket_ID and KOTGenerationItems.Item_ID=Dish.ItemID and TableNo in (" & Condition & ") and GroupName in (" & Condition1 & ")   group by Item_ID,DishName,KOTGenerationItems.Rate,DiscPer,VATPer,STPer,SCPer,TableNo,GroupName order by TableNo"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(OleDb, con)
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
            While (rdr.Read() = True)
                DataGridView2.Rows.Add(rdr(0), rdr(1), rdr(2), rdr(3), rdr(4), rdr(5), rdr(6), rdr(7), rdr(8), rdr(9), rdr(10), rdr(11), rdr(12), rdr(13), rdr(14), rdr(15))
            End While
            con.Close()
            txtCash.Text = "0.00"
            TotalCalc1()
            Calc()
        Else
            Clear()
            DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
            DataGridView2.Visible = False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você está adicionando diretamente as linhas no `DataGridView`, você deve chamar esses dois métodos em sequência para remover todas as linhas presentes no objeto.

```
DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
DataGridView2.Refresh()
```

Se você estivesse preenchendo através da propriedade `DataSource`, você usaria a seguinte sintaxe:

```
DataGridView2.DataSource = Nothing
DataGridView2.Refresh()
```

Comment: Alo @Gabriel, obrigado pela sua resposta,porem mesmo colocando os métodos  DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()  DataGridView2.Refresh() ainda continua mantendo a linhas anteriores, alguma outra sugestão??

Comment: O seu select não está retornando as linhas antigas junto?

Comment: Olhando directo na minha database nas tabela KOTGenerationItems e KOTGeneration que é onde o SELECT busca parece estar tudo normal.

Comment: Nenhuma ideia????

Comment: O método pra limpar um `DataGridView` é conforme eu expliquei na resposta... Se o seu select está retornando os valores corretos e você está usando o código que eu mostrei, então o problema está em outro lugar do código.